# unable to run logrotate postscripts command with substitute user

Tags: logrotate

logrotate(3.8.6) on RHEL7 is giving me PAM Auth rejections when running postscripts command with substitute user.

same configuration works fine when i force logrotate from shell as root, but failing with below error when logrotate is executed by cron

logrotate config

```
/var/log/rabbitmq/*.log {
    su rabbitmq rabbitmq
        daily
        dateext
        dateyesterday
        missingok
        rotate 7
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
          su rabbitmq -s /bin/sh "echo"-c
        endscript
      }
```

content in /var/log/secure

```
May  3 22:57:01 ip-10-6-78-5 su: pam_unix(su:auth): auth could not identify password for [rabbitmq]
May  3 22:57:01 ip-10-6-78-5 su: pam_unix(su:auth): auth could not identify password for [rabbitmq]
May  3 22:57:01 ip-10-6-78-5 su: pam_succeed_if(su:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "rabbitmq"
May  3 22:57:01 ip-10-6-78-5 su: pam_succeed_if(su:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "rabbitmq"
May  3 22:57:01 ip-10-6-78-5 su: FAILED SU (to rabbitmq) root on none
May  3
```

Comment: Do you have any `msg='avc:  denied  { passwd }` in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`? Do you have SELinux enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to add `sudo` before `su` and use `-c` parameter for `su` command, so your commands should looks like:
`sudo su rabbitmq -c '/bin/sh "echo"-c'`